# removing uniform columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say i have a 2D matrix `A`:

```
A = [   1   1   0   0
        1   0   0   0
        1   1   1   0];
```

`A` is not necessarily binary, or even integer (i.e., floats are possible). I want to remove any column that contains uniform valued elements. In the above example, i would get:

```
1   0
0   0
1   1
```

To make this fully general, i'd like to allow the user to select the dimension along which rows/columns/slices are removed (i.e., with a `DIM` option).

Any ideas?

Comment: Add sample I/O for a 3D case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using the min and max functions, which allow you to use the dim argument.

For example

```
index = min(A,[],1)==max(A,[],1);
A(:,index)=[];
```

will remove the columns you want. It is straightforward to do the same for rows

```
index = min(A,[],2)==max(A,[],2);
A(index,:)=[];
```

Comment: I was going to answer this but then you posted this simple solution.  Well done.

Comment: Neat. I was thinking of `index = any(diff(A,1,dim)~=0, dim)`. I'm wondering if there might be a way to make the last indexing operation truly generic with respect to `dim` as well.

Comment: beautiful! very nice

Answer (score 4):

One-liner:

```
B = A(:,range(A)~=0);  %//columns
```

The *other* one-liner is not that nice, and ugly one-liners should not be written down. :-) But is basically the same solution as S..'s, except is *way* more expensive (requires `stats` toolbox).

Please note that "generality" of subscript-based solutions doesn't extend to N-dimensional arrays as easily, because subscripting in ND arrays without checking beforehand the number of dimensions is difficult. Also, for the 1D arrays the notion of "uniformity" is a bit odd along the singleton dimension (the result is always empty).

Comment: I also quite like this one, though i can't be certain the user of my program will have access to the stats toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the neat solution provided by @S.. there is this simple hack also for your example:

```
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    T(ii) = all(A(:,ii) == sum(A(:,ii))/numel(A(:,ii)));
end
A(:,~T)
```

ans =

```
 1     0
 0     0
 1     1
```

As suggested by @gariepy the right side of the equation can be replaced with `mean` function.

```
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    T(ii) = all( A(:,ii) == mean(A(:,ii)) );
end
A(:,~T)
```

Comment: This does not work if one of the uniform columns has all negative numbers.

Comment: you could also replace `sum(A(:,ii))/numel(A(:,ii)))` with `mean(A(:,ii))`, since that is what you are calculating.

Answer (score 0):

`A(:,~all(A == repmat(A(1,:),[size(A,1) 1])))`

Inspired by @S.. but only checks if every element of the column equals the first element of the column.  Seems like a little less work for the processor than finding the min and the max, and checking for equality.